# Different program behavior depending if its main part is enclosed in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, spyder

Right at the beginning I would like to say that I am a very beginner when it comes to writing GUI applications and this is the topic of this question.

I am using Anaconda 4.1.1 as my Python distribution and Spyder as my IDE. I was trying to write a very simple window application using PyQt4 (already installed in Anaconda) or - to be precise - I copied some examples form the Internet and try to make some "experiments" with them. The results are really surprising for me.

The thing is that when I am running the following example in the IPython console:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

everything seems to be OK - I can close the window of an application whenever I want and it successfully opens once again when I am running the code once again. But when I make a small modification in the code, namely - getting rid of the `main` function:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

then I can run my program only once, because when I close it and try to run it once again - the IPython console displays the following message:

```
It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console.
```

repeating every few seconds. The Kernel itself displays something like that:

```
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
```

I don't really understand how can it happen because for me these two pieces of code should work exactly the same since the only difference between them is presence of the `main` function which (I believe) is not necessary to make this program work.  Why does it give an error the second way?

Comment: It is likely an interaction with the QtConsole inside of Spyder - Spyder uses IPython QtConsole for its terminal, and is also itself already using Qt for its own GUI, so if you aren't careful you'll run into conflicting QApplication issues.  Try it from a "vanilla" IPython terminal, does that fix it?

Comment: I searched deeper for solution of the problem and I found something out. It seems that the error occurs when the 'app' variable - which is not deleted after closing the application window - is being overridden by launching the new window. The easy solution for that is to simply assign any arbitrary value to this variable before assigning it to QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) - then the data from the "old" window will be forgotten and "new" data will be able to be assigned easily.

Comment: This also explains why the first solution works and the second one does not. The thing is that in the first solution 'app' variable is being introduced inside a function (or - procedure to be more precise) and therefore - it is a local variable which must be forgotten after the function (procedure) finisher its work. No "old" value of an 'app' variable - no conflict.

Comment: One thing I do (instead of a dummy variable) is to request the current application with `app = QApplication.instance()`, then test to see if that is None.  If it is, go ahead and make the new QApplication, and if not, then just use it without re-defining it.